# Composer installing Tripal module only above v4 and if continuing with v4, getting error with Chado module

Tags: database, composer, version-control

As part of college course work, I am required to make a genomic database with a local website with basic features. I have installed Drupal 10.2.3 with PostgreSQL 14.11 and PHP 8.3.4.

My primary question is, should I continue with Tripal version 4 even though it is still in development? If no, how do I downgrade to stable v3.10 when facing this error?

When trying to install (or downgrade to) Tripal v3.10 using

> sudo -u www-data composer require 'drupal/tripal:^3.10'

I am getting following error

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/tripal ^3.10, found drupal/tripal[dev-4.x, 4.0.0-alpha1, 4.0.0-alpha2, 4.x-dev (alias of dev-4.x)] but it does not match the constraint.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

My composer.json only contains the below

```
{
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "^12.4",
        "drupal/core": "^10.2"
    }
}
```

I am  new to Drupal as well as website development in general, and figured I would face less issues with v3 than v4 (which is still in development).

As a side note, I tried continuing with drupal/tripal:4.0.0-alpha2, and was able to proceed until I got error in Chado installation via *Home > Administration > Tripal > Data Storage > Chado > Install Chado*. From my limited understanding, it has something to do with missing "drupal_chado_installations" table but it seems to exist when I give command

> SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'drupal_chado_installations'

[image]

I am also adding the Chado installation error if someone feels it is better to continue with Tripal v4
@ http://localhost/admin/tripal/storage/chado/install

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
>
> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42P01]:
> Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "drupal_chado_installations" does
> not exist LINE 3: "drupal_chado_installations" "i" ^: SELECT
> "i"."install_id" AS "install_id", "i"."schema_name" AS "schema_name",
> "i"."version" AS "version", "i"."created" AS "created", "i"."updated"
> AS "updated" FROM "drupal_chado_installations" "i"; Array ( ) in
> Drupal\tripal_chado\Database\ChadoConnection->getAvailableInstances()
> (line 279 of
> modules/contrib/tripal/tripal_chado/src/Database/ChadoConnection.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Database\StatementWrapperIterator->execute() (Line: 851)
> Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query() (Line: 239)
> Drupal\pgsql\Driver\Database\pgsql\Connection->query() (Line: 525)
> Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Select->execute() (Line: 155)
> Drupal\pgsql\Driver\Database\pgsql\Select->execute() (Line: 279)
> Drupal\tripal_chado\Database\ChadoConnection->getAvailableInstances()
> (Line: 47) Drupal\tripal_chado\Form\ChadoInstallForm->buildForm()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 536)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm() (Line: 283)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 73)
> Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> (Line: 627) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
> (Line: 121)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext()
> (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> (Line: 181) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
> (Line: 76) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line:
> 58) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 28)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 32)
> Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 50)
> Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line:
> 51) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line:
> 36) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle() (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 704)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

My settings.php file already contains the database connection detail so many solutions mentioning that are not working

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'teak_wood_genes_db',
  'username' => 'postgres_molecular',
  'password' => '**********',
  'prefix' => 'drupal_',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '5432',
  'driver' => 'pgsql',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\pgsql\\Driver\\Database\\pgsql',
  'autoload' => 'core/modules/pgsql/src/Driver/Database/pgsql/',
);
```

Comment: There is only one question you may ask at a time on Drupal Answers.

Comment: Noted (as this is my first post). Ig my primary question is, should I continue with Tripal version 4 even though it is still in development? If no, how do I downgrade to stable v3.10 when facing this error?

Comment: There isn't a version 3.10 - that's an old versioning pattern from Drupal 7, it's not relevant to Drupal 8+. According to the module page, v4 is the only release available

Comment: Thank you! I am still getting the hang of various versions and their compatibility. So this means v4 is the only option for Drupal 10 right.

Comment: It looks that way, you can see what tags are available here: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/tripal/tree/4.x. There's no 3.x branch, so it seems the developer went straight from the old 7.3 to 4.0 for numbering

Comment: Thank you! Got a clearer picture now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.10 does not exist for that version of Drupal. Composer is telling you all the available versions.